# Azure SQL Database Timeout Issues When Connecting to Database

Tags: sql, azure, connection, timeout, razor-pages

I've been successfully connecting remotely from SQL Server Management Studio 2018 to a basic Azure SQL database for a long time, but I am now getting an error when attempting to connect.

I'm developing an ASP.NET Razor pages app that has also been able to connect fine but now the Razor App is no longer able to connect. Both SSMS and the Razor Page app are receiving the same error below. Once I deploy the Razor Page app to an App Service in Azure it functions fine.

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.6.4   
Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.8.04084
```

Here's what I've done:

- Confirmed my local IP address is allowing connections in Azure SQL to the server/database in question.
- Upgraded my installation of SQL Server Management Studio to version 19
- Converted the database from Basic to Standard and back to Basic
- Confirmed that my instance of SQL Server Management Studio can connect to other databases in Azure SQL
- I've adjusted the connection time out from 15 seconds 60 seconds
- Ran an existing Minimal API application locally connecting to an Azure SQL database without any issue.
- Executed queries fine against the database using the Query Editor within the Azure Portal.

Here's the error I am consistently receiving:

> Cannot connect to XXXXXXX.database.windows.net.
>
> Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed during the post-login phase. The connection could have timed out while waiting for server to complete the login process and respond; Or it could have timed out while attempting to create multiple active connections. The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=194; handshake=253; [Login] initialization=5; authentication=4; [Post-Login] complete=59719;  (Framework Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider)

Additionally, connecting from a console application to the same database returns the following message after

> Database 'YYYYYYYYY' on server 'XXXXXXXX.database.windows.net' is not currently available. Please retry the connection later. If the problem persists, contact customer support, and provide them the session tracing ID of '{BB3A4D62-2AB4-4481-8222-FD705A45137E}'.

Answer (score 0):

After some additional investigation I have discovered the following digging into the Azure portal.

Impact Statement: Starting at 07:33 UTC on 16 Sep 2023, you have been identified as a customer using Azure SQL Database in East US who may experience issues when trying to connect to your Database. New connections to databases hosted in a subset of this region may result in an error or timeout. Existing connections remain available to accept new requests, however if those connections are terminated you might not be able to re-connect.

Workaround: Customers might be able to avoid the aforementioned errors by using connection policy redirect.

Current Status: We have identified that during a brief period of time an underlying network infrastructure has suffered with power issues, resulting on downstream impact for SQL Database in East US region. After further investigation, we have found some unhealthy compute nodes impacting our service on East US region as well. We continue directing all our efforts towards bringing the affected nodes back to a healthy state. The next update will be provided in 60 minutes, or as events warrant.